# SQL How to get the records where contains keywords from another table

Tags: sql, split, sql-like, contains

I need help in SQL to get the records where it contains the keywords from another table

I have a main table and another table for the keywords.

**Main Table**

| ID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | colored paper |
| 12 | red shirt |
| 13 | antiblack shoe |
| 14 | yellow desk |

**Keywords Table**

| Keywords |
| --- |
| red |
| yellow |
| black |
| green |

**Expected Output**

| ID | item |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | red shirt |
| 14 | yellow desk |

The expected output is the records that contains the color from the keywords table
The item with ID 11 (contain colo**red**) and 13 (contain anti**black**) are not included because it is not referred to as "color" meaning

How can I use split each item name and then match it with the keywords table to get the record only fully matched with keywords?
Thankyou!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Don't make people waste their time writing answers for 'wrong' dbms...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Main
WHERE substr(keywords,1,instr(keywords,' ')) IN(
    SELECT distinct keywords FROM Keywords
)
```

another way

```
SELECT m.* FROM main AS m
LEFT JOIN keywords AS k ON m.item LIKE '%'||k.keywords||'%'
WHERE k.keywords IS NOT NULL
```

code above run in SQLite